# Limit duration of skype call

Tags: skype

I'd like to limit the duration of a skype call to x minutes. Due to the fact that there's no option on skype I need another solution. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

... have a daemon that monitors call sessions and use the "SET CALL FINISHED" method?

Comment: do you mean via the skype4py api?

Comment: @Kai: yes.  I haven't found the complete reference of the API through DBus (which would be my personal preference) but the Python Client API library appears complete.

Comment: where did you find the dbus api?

Comment: I use D-Feet DBus analyser.